# Function that returns an equation

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I am writing a script to calculate the definite integral of an equation. I'm writing a helper function that would take in coefficients as parameters and return a function of x.

```
def eqn(x, k, c, a):
    return ((k*x + c**(1-a))
```

Next, I define a function that calculates the definite integral, using quad imported from scipy:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
def integral(eqn, c_i, y_i):
    integral_i, integral_err = quad(eqn, c_i, y_i)
    print integral_i
```

Then I call the function by passing in parameters

```
k = calc_k(7511675,1282474,0,38,2)
eqn = carbon_path_eqn(x, k, 7511675, 2)
carbon_path_def_int(eqn,0,38)
```

However, I get an error saying that 'name x is not defined'. I understand that `x` isn't defined globally, but I'm wondering how I can write a helper function, that takes in parameters, and still returns a function of x that can be used in `quad`?

Thank you!

PS -
[@bpachev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4317531/bpachev), this is a follow up from the other post

Comment: Your `eqn` does not return a function; it returns a value, number based on the inputs, `x`, etc.

Comment: Doesn't `quad` have a examples of using a function that takes auxiliary parameters?  Have you experimented with the quad examples?

Comment: You know you can always just do [symbolic](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html) and [numeric integration](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#numeric-integrals) with Sympy, right? Why are you reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake here is that the function 'eqn' does not return a function, it returns the *value* of a function at some point x, given parameters k,c,a.

quad should be passed a function (in your case, eqn) where the first argument (in your case, x) is assumed to be the variable over which the function is integrated. You also need to pass quad a tuple of the remaining parameters (in your case (k,c,a)) and two limits (in your case, c_i,y_i). In other words, call quad like this:

```
quad(eqn,c_i,y_i,args=(k,c,a))
```

This is all explained in the scipy documentation http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html.

Comment: that helped a lot! i updated my `integral` function with `k,c,a` parameters as well as the `quad` function. it also made me realize that I didn't need to define `eqn` as a global variable. i just call 'eqn' as a parameter in the `integral` function and i'm good to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you asked. However, as someone else has mentioned, sympy would probably make your life much easier. For instance, suppose you need to be able to evaluate integrals of functions of **x** such as f in the code below, where **a** and **b** are arbitrary constants. Here's how you can use sympy to do that.

Define the function, integrate it with respect to **x** and save the result, then evaluate the result for values of **a**, **b** and **x**.

[image: sample use of sympy]